# check which radio button is selected

Tags: html, angularjs

I need to check witch radio button is selected.

```
<div class="cClearFloat cInputSpace cRadioAdmin">
    <label class="cLabelJa"><input type="radio" value="Ja" name="Admin" ng-model="radioJa">Ja</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="Admin" value="Nein" ng-model="radioNein">Nein</label>
</div>
```

How can i check in angularjs if the radio button is selcted?
i tried it too but by me it's not working.

```
if ($scope.radioJa.checked == true) {
       $scope.saveUser();
       $scope.currentUser.isAdmin = 'Ja';
    } else if($scope.radioNein == true) {
       $scope.currentUser.isAdmin = 'Nein';
       $scope.saveUser();
    } else {
        alert("Bitte füllen Sie alle Felder korrekt aus!", "Fehler");
    }
}
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<label class="cLabelJa"><input type="radio" value="Ja" name="Admin" ng-model="radioJa">Ja</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="Admin" value="Nein" ng-model="radioNein">Nein</label>
```

In this case you have same name, but it has two difference ng-model name. It should be same..

Both the radio buttons value will be 'undefined', if you have not selected them..

To check if it is selected, you can use the following

```
if ( !$scope.radioJa ){
     alert('comes here if the radio button is not selected');        
}
if ( $scope.radioJa ){
     alert('comes here if the radio button is selected'); 
     alert("and the value of $scope.radioJa will be `Ja` if the 1st radio button is selected");        
}
```

Comment: so i need to make this?

Comment: $scope.radioNein = false;
$scope.radioJa = true;

Comment: its nearlly working. The 'Ja' button is working but not the 'Nein' Button.

Comment: i have edited.. both the inputs have same names but different ng-model in the input tags..

Comment: i wrote into the first radio button: checked="checked" but this radio button is not selected.

Comment: what is the Nein button giving.. undefined?

Comment: when the 'Nein' Button is checked and then i press Speichern (for check it) its going into this if: if($scope.radioJa)

Comment: the problem was that a radiobutton can't handle with ng-model(so was it by me). now i got a solution. :) but ty for your help.